# Gradle error on all new project: Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error whenever i start a new project. It doesn't configure.

> Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>              Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

**build.gradle:**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: clean and rebuild project.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: Invalid package.xml found and failed to parse using fallback. Renaming C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml to C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml.bad
Found corrupted package.xml at C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\package.xml
Found corrupted package.xml at C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml